# How to use javaFX with javaFXML

Tags: java

Is it possible to combine JavaFX and JavaFXML screens in the same project that I can switch from a screen built using scene builder and the next screen is built using JavaFX?

Comment: Are you talking about the main screen built with scene builder, and the next programmatically?

Comment: yes the main screen is built using scene builder and the next is built programmaticaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there is no difference from calling screens programmatically or scene builder generated fxml files. You can launch the first window from code or fxml, and then call another screen from code or fxml.

**Example: Main.java**

```java
package sample;  

import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;  
import javafx.scene.Parent;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class Main extends Application {  

  @Override  
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{  
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));  
      primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");  

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);  

      primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
      primaryStage.show();  
  }  


  public static void main(String[] args) {  
      launch(args);  
  }  
}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
package sample;  

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;  
import javafx.fxml.FXML;  
import javafx.scene.Group;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class Controller {  

  @FXML  
 private javafx.scene.control.Button myButton;  

 @FXML 
 private void testButton(ActionEvent e) {  
      System.out.println("Button Clicked...");  
      Stage currentStage = (Stage) myButton.getScene().getWindow();  
      Group root = new Group();  

      Stage stage = new Stage();  
      stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");  
      stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));  
      stage.show();  

      // Hide this current window (if this is what you want)  
      currentStage.close();  
  }  
}
```

**sample.fxml**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>  
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>  

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">  
 <children>  
 <Button fx:id="myButton" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="59.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#testButton" text="Click me!" />  
 </children>  
</AnchorPane>
```

**Code explanation:**
An initial window is launched with a button, the button id and onAction are declared in the Controller class to launch another window, and close the initial one. If you don't want to hide the initial screen just comment that out.